# php array sorting with next value difference

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

can anyone help me with this following Array sorting

**Input**

```
$array=array(1,2,3,6,7,8,100,101,200);
```

**Output:**

```
$new_array=array(
    0=>array(1,2,3),
    1=>array(6,7,8),
    2=>array(100,101),
    3=>array(200)
);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the rules of `"sorting"`?

Comment: as you can see after (1,2,3) 4,5 is missing so 1,2,3 will be one Array. similarly (7,8)  will be another one etc and finnaly the whole Array should look like the above mentioned Output array

Comment: That's not "sorting", it's *chunking*. The input is already *sorted*.

Comment: so deceze, you have nice theoritical Background i think, can you make the expected Output Array from the Input Array??

Comment: Perfect example about how NOT to ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array=array(1,2,3,6,7,8,100,101,200);

    $new_array = array();
    $lastNumber = '';
    foreach($array as $number) {

        if($lastNumber === '') {
            $otherArray = array($number);
        }
        elseif($lastNumber + 1 !== $number) {
            $new_array[] = $otherArray;
            $otherArray = array($number);
        }
        else{
            $otherArray[] = $number;
        }
        $lastNumber = $number;
    }
    $new_array[] = $otherArray;
    print_r($new_array);
```

Comment: That's quite overcomplicating things... O_o

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the array and check the distance to the next element in the array. If this distance is larger then one add a new sub array:

```
$array=array(1,2,3,6,7,8,100,101,200);
$result=array(array());

for($i=0; $i<count($array)-1; $i++)
{
      if($array[$i+1]-$array[$i]==1)
      {
            // If difference to next number is one -> push
            array_push($result[count($result)-1], $array[$i]);
      }
      else
      {
            // ... else: Push and create new array for the next element
            array_push($result[count($result)-1], $array[$i]);
            array_push($result, array());
       }
}

// Push the last number
array_push($result[count($result)-1], $array[$i]);

print_r($result);
```

Just a different approach with `array_push()`...

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple: loop through the numbers, remember the last one, if the current number is not the successor of the last one, add a new array to your result, push into the last array in your result.

```
$result = [];
$last = null;

foreach ($array as $number) {
    if ($last !== $number - 1) {
        $result[] = [];
    }
    $result[count($result) - 1][] = $number;
    $last = $number;
}
```

You could even get rid of `$last` and directly read the *last array element of the last array element of `$result`*, but that would make the code actually more complicated.